# Comparing coefficient across datasets - Cox Proportional Hazard model

Tags: regression-coefficients, cox-model, credit-scoring

I am doing a study of credit risk in europe for the period of 2006 - 2016 by using the Cox Proportional Hazard Model (time costant edition) in R (coxph). I have succesfully implemented the model for the whole period with 8 independent variables.

Now I want to make 2 subgroups (2006 - 2010 and 2011 - 2016) in order to compare the coefficients between the two subgroups. I have created a dataset of the sub groups by with a dummy variable (Subgroup) so that 2006 - 2010 = 0 and 2011 - 2016 = 1.

What is the next step in the analysis in order to compare the coefficients in the two sub groups?

Dataset: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bslulf4dud6zaxq/0610og1116.csv?dl=0

I dont know if i have done it correctly in the code below?

[image: so far?]

Answer (score 1):

R takes care of creating dummy variables. You just need to include qualitative predictor in formula inside `coxph`.

E.g. if `X` and `Y` are quantitative and `Z` is qualitative,

```
coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ X + Y + Z)
```

should work.

You may also add interactions to check if `Z` affects coefficients of `X` and `y`:

```
coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ X + Y + Z + X:Z + Y:Z)
```

Comment: Thank you @Łukasz - could you please be a bit more specific? The following is from my model covering the whole period (2006 - 2016):

cox.FINAL<-coxph(Surv(N, Konkurs) ~ ROA+GDP+LIBOR+PCL.TA+VIX+DEPTA,data=CoxData)

Comment: I assume that in `CoxData`you have a variable called `YEAR` or somthing similar. First, you have to cut it to get subgroups (2006 - 2010 and 2011 - 2016) : `CoxData$YEARCUT<-cut(CoxData$YEAR, c(2006,2010,2016), include.lowest=T` and then use it in `coxph`: `coxph(Surv(N, Konkurs) ~ ROA+GDP+LIBOR+PCL.TA+VIX+DEPTA+YEARCUT,data=CoxData)`

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me. The variable N in my cox model is the time to event / censoring. I have constructed my dataset in excel and imported to R afterwards. So i dont have the "years" variable. 

I have created the sub datasets manually - how do i compare coefficients now? 

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Add YEAR variable to your Excel

Comment: I am sorry, but is not possible to make a clear cut like that. Constructing a dataset for this purpose must be constructed in a speciale manner. The time to event variable must be present. 

But i have found another solution on how to implement the dummy variable. 

Could you please help me with the comparison of coefficients?

Comment: Now I think I do not understand your problem... Why you can't add YEAR variable? Or maybe you can add SUBGROUP variable with values 'subgroup 1' and 'subgroup 2'?

Comment: Yes - I have created the subgroups now with a dummy variable, 0 = 2006 - 2010 and 1 = 2011 - 2016. So now i should be ready to implement the cox model where i am able to compare the coefficients, right?

Comment: Exactly. coxph(Surv(N, Konkurs) ~ ROA+GDP+LIBOR+PCL.TA+VIX+DEPTA+SUBGROUP,data=CoxData)

Comment: i have updated the text for the question. So you are able to see the data and my code so far ! Thank you in advance !

Comment: Subgroup is non-significant, so it doesn't affect time to event

Comment: Subgroup is a dummy variable that indicates which period of the time the observation relates to

Sub group: 0 = years 2006 - 2010 and 1 = 2011 - 2016. 

Are you sure that this is correct ?